# Azure B2C call azure function with JWT token or code kept as policy key

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

is it possible to call azure function without hardcoding function code in service url?
For example using policy key and sending it as query string/header. I don't want it to be exposed.
Alternative is to use AAD auth on app service level, but that would require generating JWT token before step "SendClaims" and it could possibly led to authenticated users having access to this function.
Thanks for any help.

Edit:
Ok, I did it as suggested and I got to a point where I have everything set up.
I can request a working token using postman and authorize properly to azure function.
I have debugged said token in user journey by outputting it as user claim (I confirmed that acquire step is working), but I get an error on calling function

> AADB2C90027: Basic credentials specified for 'Azure-Functions-Notify-New-User-Registered' are invalid. Check that the credentials are correct and that access has been granted by the resource.

So far my xml file looks like that:

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Aquire JWT token to call azure function</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="Azure-Functions-Notify-New-User-Registered-AccessToken">
      <DisplayName>Acquire JWT token to call azure function</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{my-tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token</Item>
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Basic</Item>
        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Form</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationUsername" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_NotifyNewUserRegisteredClientId" />
        <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationPassword" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_NotifyNewUserRegisteredSecret" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="grant_type" DefaultValue="client_credentials" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="scope" DefaultValue="https://{my-tenant}/{my-resoruce-id}/.default" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="bearerToken" PartnerClaimType="access_token" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>

<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Azure-Functions-Notify-New-User-Registered</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="Azure-Functions-Notify-New-User-Registered">
      <DisplayName>Call Azure Function when new user registers</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl">{my-azure-function-with-function-code}</Item>
        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Bearer</Item>
        <Item Key="UseClaimAsBearerToken">bearerToken</Item>
        <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">false</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="bearerToken"/>
      </InputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

And my user journey:

```
    <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="Azure-Functions-Notify-New-User-Registered-AccessToken" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Azure-Functions-Notify-New-User-Registered-AccessToken" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="8" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="Azure-Functions-Notify-New-User-Registered" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Azure-Functions-Notify-New-User-Registered" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="9" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protect it with AAD. Get the JWT to the function app using this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/secure-rest-api#oauth2-bearer-authentication

No you don’t need to worry about the user getting this JWT, that’s impossible unless you decide to output this JWT as a claim in the relying party section.

Comment: You should troubleshoot this outside of B2C. Use POSTman to obtain a token, and send it to your Azure Function. Then youll see exactly what its complaining about. B2C policy config looks fine.

Comment: As I said, I did test it. Obtaining JWT token and using it with postman works great. I am using exactly the same parameters in my framework policy as in postman.
I have also debugged it in B2C by commenting step number 8 and just adding "bearerToken" to the final claims and it was properly populated. So the problem is with step number 8, but as I said I have tried with postman with all the same parameters and it was fine. What am I missing? 
BTW I am sorry for editing your answer. Just a misclick.

Comment: Are you able to use App Insights to get the logs? In the logs you can see the values being sent to AAD /token endpoint and also the value of bearerToken. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights

Comment: Values send to token endpoint are ok, bearerToken value is also populated.
Issue is with step 8 which is actually calling secured rest endpoint and I cannot pinpoint mistake, as when I copy all the values to postman I can access function.
I've also double checked if 

        <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationUsername" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_NotifyNewUserRegisteredClientId" />
        <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationPassword" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_NotifyNewUserRegisteredSecret" />

have correct values.

Comment: So, basically. I have good token (working in postman), good parameters, solution 1:1 with docs how to call secure rest endpoint and it does not work. I wonder what little thing am I missing.

Comment: Did you decode the value of bearerToken and compare it to the token you are using in POSTMan?

Comment: Ok, I need to make myself clear. Step 7 is getting a token and saving it to bearerToken claim. I have tested it two ways. First - comment out step 8 and output it as a claim of a final token (then I copy pasted the nested value to postman and to jwt.ms). Second - after step 7 has executed application insights logs are outputting bearerToken value. The bearerToken value works when I want to use it to call my protected azure function. So step 7 is out of the equation because it simply works as it should. I don't get any useful logs regarding step 8, but it is done the same way as in docs.

Comment: Answering your question I did decode it and I have nothing to compare to because this is the one that I use in postman :) So step 7 works like a charm.

Comment: It is like my azure function auth is blocking call from azure b2c but allows from postman. I have even tried to set <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item> and create Authorization header manually via claim transformation and <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Header</Item>

Comment: I have removed all policies from identity framework and added them again. It is working now.